# build errors Access denied to neo4j-server-2.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar

Tags: maven, neo4j

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)

> (building 2.0 snapshot) How to reproduce : 
>   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6118671
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project neo4j-server-advanced: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server-advanced:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:tests:2.0-SNAPSHOT
>   from/to tinkerpop-repository (http://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access
>   denied to:
>   http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/2.0-SNAPSHOT/neo4j-server-2.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar,
>   ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]

any ideas?

Comment: It simply means you have enterted wrong artifact id or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you won't find that jar in the tinkerpop maven repository.

Here's a settings.xml file with the correct location of the Neo4j snapshot repository:
http://dist.neo4j.org/settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
                    <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
                    <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
                    <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
                    <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Taking a look, the artifacts [in there](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/2.0-SNAPSHOT/) look slightly outdated.
So to get a fresh version, you could just do *mvn install* on the module in community/server first.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

% perl -p -i.bak -e  's{tinkerpop.com}{repo.maven.apache.org}g'  advanced/server-advanced/pom.xml

% perl -p -i.bak -e  's{tinkerpop.com}{repo.maven.apache.org}g'  enterprise/server-enterprise/pom.xml